# For what values of $x$ is $f$ differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $f(x)=(\sin{\pi x},(1-x)^3)$. For what values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $f$ differentiable.

How would one go about answering this question? I believe I should evaluate the coordinate functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ separately to determine for what values of x they are both differentiable. But how do I evaluate if the coordinate functions themselves are differentiable? Aren't both coordinate functions always differentiable? I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Sometimes things are easier than we expect

Comment: @Siminore, would you mind giving me a push in the right direction?